# Fill column in Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to set Microsoft word for two column and then when write something instead of going to next line go to next column?

[image: choose two column]

You know that in default it fills one column and then go to next one.

Comment: You can add manual column break (page layout - breaks - column) to specify where you need the end of a column. However, if I understand correctly your question, you need to fill the columns like you work in tables in Excel. In this case columns are not the right choice for you. Use a table with two columns instead and set all borders to nothing to make your document look like as formatted with columns.

Comment: OK. thanks. you are right I think it is not possible to do it. I can do it only by table.